# Node.js: test assert that a pointer points to myType, not only to object

Tags: javascript, node.js, assert, typeof

I've a "UserService" object that only contains functions like:

- exports.usersList
- exports.insertUser
- exports.registerUser
- etc...

In the test file I have:

```
var userController = serviceFactory.getUserService();
```

Now, I've to assert that `userController` points to an `UserService` but if I do:

```
typeof userController
```

It returns only `object` type and not "UserService" as I want.
How can I check it trough node.js assertions?

Comment: How do you create your service ? Doesn't instanceof work for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you defined a class (that is a Function in JS), just try [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)

```
// in your user_controller.js file
Function UserController() {
  ...
}
UserController.prototype.userList = function() {
  ...
}
module.exports = UserController

// in another file
var userController = new UserController();
userController instanceof UserController // prints true
```